# Maven dependency architecture - circular dependency

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, pom.xml, circular-dependency

I have a main maven jar projectA but it uses as dependencies maven projects like projectB, projectC, but projectB uses as dependency projectC and so on with projectN.

It happened because it started as a small project but it started growing so fast without thinking about the architecture. Now it is a problem, specially when many people is working on those different projects using git.

Any ideas for solving that problem?

Comment: role them into one jar or accept you are in dependency hell and demand time to fix it

Comment: Simple answer: Clean your architecture and your module structure which will solve your problems...